# Forcing ArcMap to recognize text field in CSV file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, csv

Related to [Data-type detection in ArcGIS table loading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/410/data-type-detection-in-arcgis-table-loading)

I have a CSV file which contains a mixture of numeric and text fields:

```
ID,Txt,Int,Dbl
12345,abc,45,56.78
12346,9,65,23.12
12347,10,66,23.13
```

According to this [Esri article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/esritrainingmatters/2008/11/25/formatting-excel-data-for-use-in-arcgis-desktop/) if the top 8 rows contain a text value, the field will be classified as text, yet I am finding that the second field is classified as Long. This means that the value "abc" is omitted:

[image]

How can I force ArcMap to recognise this as a text field, while maintaining the data in CSV format?

A workaround will be to create a geodatabase table, define the field as text, and Load the data, but I'm hoping to keep the table in CSV (it's the output of another process).

Comment: Here is the full spec for the record:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Interestingly, it did not fully worked for me...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at the "Overriding how text files are formatted" section in the help topic on [Adding an ASCII or text file table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000):

> You can override how delimited text files are displayed within ArcGIS
>   by using the schema.ini files. An example of when you would want to
>   use the schema.ini file to override the default behavior is when
>   ArcGIS is misinterpreting a field type. The following example shows
>   how to do this for a field called PLOTS which should be displayed as
>   type Text but is being interpreted as type Double.
>
> ```
> [Trees.CSV]
> Col14=PLOTS Text
> ```
>
> Note that you may need to create a schema.ini file if one is not
>   present and you need to override how delimited text files are
>   displayed in ArcGIS. For more information on the schema.ini file, do a
>   search for schema.ini on the [Microsoft MSDN website](http://links.esri.com/microsoft_msdn).

Comment: Thanks for that - it does the trick. There seems to be a problem with ArcGIS scanning the first 8 rows automatically, though.

Comment: I had to add "MaxScanRows = 0" since the "ColX=name Text" thing didn't seem to work 100% on its own.

Comment: Has anyone tried this using arcpy on Linux? I'd guess that this would only work on Windows since schema.ini is all tied up with the Micrsoft ODBC cruft.