# Some data loss when Importing Personal Geodatabase Table from Excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, excel, personal-geodatabase

When import table from excel some data were loss. I was trying to change field type but I can't solve this error. I have attached an example image to show the problem.

[image: comparison of Excel and geodatabase values]

Comment: related to [How to force ArcGIS to recognize a text field in a CSV file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30670/how-to-force-arcgis-to-recognize-a-text-field-in-a-csv-file/30671#30671) which should help

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS uses Microsoft technology to read Office formats, Excel and Access. The default is to read the first 8 rows to determine column datatypes. Changing this registry key forces the entire table to be read first. The infered datatypes and widths are much more accurate, especially for .csv.

\hklm\software\wow6432node\microsoft\jet\engines\excel

typeGuessRows change to 0

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to try:

1. save the Excel file in DBase (.dbf) format,
2. or save as CSV file,
3. and/or reorder the data so that the value of the first row contains a letter.

The import isn't very smart and when it sees a number value for the field, it makes that field's type a number. Reordering may make it interpret the field as text. Notice that the field containing 'NA' values is interpreted as text. See if the first row contains 'NA'. If so, reordering such that the first rows has text in both fields should force it to interpret both fields as text.