# How to make ArcCatalog recognize numbers in a csv/text file as numbers?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

I am creating feature classes from [GNS txt files](http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.html) in ArcCatalog (10.2). When I do this with the file for Bolivia (bl.txt), the feature class is created correctly. When I try to do this with the file for Argentina, the columns LONG and LAT are recognized as `Text` instead of `Double`, so I cannot assign them as X and Y fields.

The formats for both files are identical. Both ar.txt and bl.txt contain only numeric values in the columns LONG and LAT, with `.` as decimal separator. I cannot identify any differences between the two files to explain the different behavior. Is there a way to force ArcGIS to recognize these columns as double precision fields?

As a workaround I can import the `txt`  files in an Excel spreadsheet and create the feature class correctly from that, but I believe I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. I still don't understand how a column containing only numbers can be interpreted correctly sometimes but as `Text`  in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved following https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30671/10436 with Schema.ini:

```
[ar.txt]
Col4="LAT" Double
Col5="LONG" Double
```