# When (and why?) does ArcGIS Pro modify schema.ini files?

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv

I am using a schema.ini file to control how CSV data is read in ArcGIS Pro, as documented in [Forcing ArcMap to recognize text field in CSV file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30670/forcing-arcmap-to-recognize-text-field-in-csv-file).

Apparently ArcGIS Pro is making changes to schema.ini. The file currently looks like this:

```
[project-sunroof-census_tract.csv]
Col1=region_name Text
[Philly_SolarPanelApprovals.csv]
Col2=ZIP Text
Col3=permitissuedate Date
[ACSDT5Y2019.B19013_data_with_overlays_2021-09-14T145552.csv]
Col3=B19013_001E Text
Col4=B19013_001M Text
```

Here's the thing: I added data type overrides for the first two files, but not the third one. The third file is a Census data download which, for some reason, has integer data quoted. I actually *don't* want it read as text, and did not add this to the file.

Obviously, I can fix it, but I'm trying to understand what caused ArcGIS Pro to do this. I added two other ACS tables (CSV files) that were *not* added to schema.ini this way. I didn't edit any of the data in ArcGIS Pro (and, so far as I know, CSVs cannot be edited in ArcGIS Pro like DBFs or the attribute table of a shapefile). All three were joined to a spatial layer and exported to a geodatabase.

I also don't think this behavior occurs (?) if there is no preexisting schema.ini in the CSV folder, but since I haven't been able to identify the triggering behavior, I can't test this.

Comment: I know for certain that running GP tools will cause the schema.ini to be created or updated. However, there could be other actions in Pro that trigger it. (Possibly adding a CSV to the project; but I dont know for sure all the actions/triggers)

Comment: I think this question is better asked over on the ESRI community forum site as @KHibma says all sorts of application events may trigger the update of the ini file and only ESRI could answer that?